# Temporary zeros to nans

Tags: python, pandas

```
      Values     Offset    Result
a1    1.05       2.00   
a2    2.98       1.00           
a3    1.01       nan  
a4    0.02       3.00
a5    0.01       2.00
a6    2.11       1.00
a7    0.08       nan
a8    3.18       nan
a9    2.61       nan
...
..
.
```

I have a df similar to above. I have a custom function doing negative dynamic offseting for the values. Before applying that func, I am filling nans with 0 then converting the column to int for proper slicing.

```
df['Offset'] = df['Offset'].fillna(0)
df['Offset'] = df['Offset'].astype(int)
```

After that I am running my custom func which is doing the job. But nans in the offset column becomes 0 so I want 0's back to nans like originally before? I tried like below:

```
buffer = np.where(np.isnan(df['Offset']))
```

this gave me the index locations of previous nans but I don't know how to implement? (convert 0's to nans like original)
Thank you,

Comment: `buffer = np.isnan(df['Offset'])` and later, after your function,  `df.loc[buffer, 'Offset'] = np.nan`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need leave a `mask` there

```
m = df.isnull()
df['Offset'] = df['Offset'].fillna(0)
df['Offset'] = df['Offset'].astype(int)
df = df.mask(m)
```

Comment: Use `df['Offset'].fillna(0, downcast='infer')` you can replace 2 lines.

Answer (score 1):

I believe this will work as well

```
df.loc[df['Offset'] == 0,'Offset'] = np.nan
```

Edit for if lines have 0 naturally

```
indexfilter = df.loc[df['Offset'].isna()].index #Use this before fill NaN with 0
```

Apply normal function, then do below to convert back to NaN.

```
df.loc[df['Offset'].index.isin(indexfilter),'Offset'] = np.nan
```

Comment: This might not work if original data contains `0` along with `nan`.